# Webpack file-loader and Svelte style background image not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, svelte

I have **Svelte** with **Webpack** and it's **file-loader** installed

`webpack.config.js`'s `modules.esports.module.rules` have:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
        'file-loader',
    ],
},
```

In `App.svelte` I have working code:

```
<script>
    import smile from './smile.jpg';
</script>

<img src={smile}>
```

That makes working output:

```
<img src="c6999a26a16dceaf99e54f8f00ecd0c5.jpg">
```

**But**

This code:

```
<style>
    .smile {background: url('./smile.jpg')}
</style>

<div class="smile"></div>
```

Outputs:

```
<div class="smile svelte-uv69f3"></div>

.smile.svelte-uv69f3 {
    background: url([object Module]);
}
```

But expected css output is:

```
.smile.svelte-uv69f3 {
    background: url('c6999a26a16dceaf99e54f8f00ecd0c5.jpg');
}
```

So, could it be fixed? Thx

Comment: You need to use [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader) for that

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, Webpack's documentation did not mention it https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/ (ctrl+F to background: url('./icon.png'))